# How to resolve Ultimaker Cura 4.0 messed up display

Tags: ultimaker-cura, linux

I'm using Ultimaker Cura on a Manjaro KDE installation with a 4K monitor and a scaling of 1.7.

All text is misaligned in the Ultimaker Cura application.

How can I make it look as it should ?

[image: Text and Icon alignment is offset in Ultimaker Cura application window]

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! May incur an uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: You could just [open an issue](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues/new/choose) at the developers site, they might know exactly what is wrong or if it is a bug? If the latter, the community is grateful you found and reported it!